# Why is a greyscale OpenGL ES texture from AVCaptureSession displaced?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, avcapturesession

Here's the problem, I am working on a little project on the iPhone with OpenGL ES. I started with Brad Larson's [ColorTracking App](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip) (Big thanks to Brad for providing it) and tuned it to my needs.

Everything is working fine, however, when I use the `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` for the `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey` in my `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, since I'll be working on greyscale images and don't need any colors anyway, the resulted image on the screen is translated along the y-axis, and the part which goes off-screen is rendered on the top:

Here is a a screenshot:

[image]

Of course you need to change the data type in the `glTexImage2D` call from `GL_RGBA` to `GL_LUMINANCE` for this to work.

This behavior doesn't occur using the `GL_RGBA` texture from a `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` capture session.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix this?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the edit. I have one simple question though. After giving it some thoughts, I have found the problem and its solution. Should I answer my own question or give the answer in the comment section ?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable (and even encouraged) to leave an answer to your own question, if it's a real answer that clearly explains how you solved the problem. That way, others know the problem is solved and people who might encounter this in the future will be able to learn from your solution.

Comment: Will do, when it lets me, i.e. in 5 hours ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer for this problem:

the `glTextImage2D` call should be changed to get the right base address of the `CVImageBufferRef`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer));

// should become 

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0));
```

In case of the `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` we need to get the first plane which contains the luminance data. Notice the data type is `GL_LUMINANCE` and the data pointer is `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer, 0)`